# Extracting email body from email--for text analytics

Tags: sql-server-2008, text, analytics, business-intelligence

I want some way to extract email content from email that we send/receive in account.

further i need to develop an algorithm to extract data from email content

this question is in context to Text Analytics

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? What exactly is the step that you are having trouble with? Is it getting the emails off the server, trimming off headers, or what?

Comment: You want to store that exacted emails in Excel or what?

Comment: briefly describe your question...

Answer (score 0):

you have to do some R & D on Email extractor